# Regular expression to replace certain word between brackets with multiline

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

Need to find and replace `type=`

```
@Define(
         *          out="type",
         *          name="some_val",
         *          type="value",
         *          some="description",
         *      ),
```

To find between brackets in certain @Define with multiline:

```
/@Define\(((.|\n)*?)\)/g
```

But this doesn't work with multiline:

```
/@Define\((type=)\)/g
```

Comment: Where exactly do you use this regex?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew In vscode search input but for test use regex101.com

Comment: Search in the current file, or all files (aka magnifying glass)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you don't have `)` in brackets,

```
(                 // select as $1
  @Define\(       // literal `@Define(`
  [^)]*?          // any amount of not `)`
)                 // end $1
type="[^"]*"      // type with any simple string
```

```
from:
(@Define\([^)]*?)type="[^"]*"
to:
$1type="bar"
```